# components get render even routed out on componentWillMount method?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-router-flux

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    console.log(currentUser);
    if (currentUser) {
      Actions.mainScreen();
    }
  }

  render(){...}
}
```

Basically the idea very simple, once user comes to `LoginScreen`, it checks if the user existed, if yes, instead of render this component, redirect to another component instead.

The problem with the above code is that, `LoginScreen` still gets to `render` for 1 to 2 seconds before render `mainScreen`. Wondering if this is the way to handle such routing conditionally in `React-Native-Router-Flux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem. declare a state

```
state = {
   isChecking: true
}
```

in your componentWillMount

```
componentWillMount() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    Actions.mainScreen();
  } else {
    this.setState({ isChecking: false });
  }
});
}
```

or better still with the async/await syntax

```
async componentWillMount() {
let user = await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged;
user ? Actions.mainScreen() : this.setState({ isChecking: false });
```

In your render method first, check when you are still checking or not. If so just render an activityIndicator. At the very very top of your render method check whether you are still checking or not.

```
render() {
if (this.state.isChecking) {
  return (
    <View
      style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", flex:1 }}
    >
      <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} />
    </View>
  );
   // rest of your loginScreen components
}
```

Comment: On your await portion, `user` will always be defined and when doing a console log, it return the following log `function r(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);return Hs(o,n,e),t.apply(this,e)}`

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't test it. I assume it will work. Let me edit my answer to reflect this change